# Use of `this` in Scala Class definition

Tags: scala, class, apache-spark, this

I am going over Advanced Analytics in Spark book and in the chapter two it has the following code snippet:

```
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
class NAStatCounter extends Serializable { 
    val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter() 
    var missing: Long = 0
    def add(x: Double): NAStatCounter = { 
        if (java.lang.Double.isNaN(x)) {
            missing += 1 
        } else { 
           stats.merge(x)
        }
        this
    }   
    def merge(other: NAStatCounter): NAStatCounter = {
        stats.merge(other.stats)
        missing += other.missing
        this
    }
    override def toString = {
        "stats: " + stats.toString + " NaN: " + missing
    }
}
```

Here I am really confused with the use of `this`. In both functions `add` and `merge` is it referring to the original `NAStatCounter` the code is defining?

The book comments:

> "The merge method incorporates the statistics that are tracked by
>   another NAStatCounter instance into the current instance. Both of
>   these methods return this so that they can be easily chained
>   together."

What do they mean when they say the use of `this` eases chaining?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The last line of a method in Scala is the return value. Meaning you don't have to say `return this;` how you might in many languages.
2. It may help to imagine that instead of the parameter to the functions (add and merge) being another NAStateCounter, it is a string or some other primitive. The parameter has nothing to do with the "this" that the add and merge methods are returning.
3. "this" in this context points to an instance of NAStatCounter so when you say something like

   var nsCounter = new NAStatCounter()

the "this" in the add and merge methods are pointing back to the instance, which is nsCounter. So when you call add for instance, it does its thing and then returns nsCounter, at which point you can call any method defined on nsCounter.

nsCounter.add(d1).toString()

Answer (score 4):

It means you can do this

```
counter.add(d1).add(d2).merge(c).add(d3)
```

This is called method chaining.

Comment: But how does use of `this` helps here?

Comment: If the return type of `add` is `Unit`, then you can't call `counter.add(d1).add(d2)` right? `.add(d2)` can only be called on a `NAStatsCounter` so if `.add(d1)` returns nothing how could this work? hence you return a reference to the original object itself, or `this`. Same as in Java.